# Laravel:Display only own post

Tags: laravel-5

hello team I have three table users, reqs and user_req. Many user submit data to the reqs table. Iwant only own user to view his/her post

```
  public function index()
{
    $req = DB::table('particulars')
        ->join('reqs', 'particulars.particular_id', "=", 'reqs.particular_id')
        ->select('particulars.*', 'reqs.*')
        ->where('status_req', '=', 'pending')
        ->where('status_issue', '=', 'not issued')
        ->get();
    return view('requester.index', compact('req'));
}
```

The function above display other user request. .....please help

Comment: Specify what data particulars table holds and what is particular_id.

Comment: there is other table called particular with particular_id that used to display particular name in table

Comment: You are not filtering the data based on currently active user. You can add a where clause to filter the data  for a user by using it's id.

Comment: sorry can you help me with that

Comment: Ok. Tell me about your table schemas.

Comment: I have user table and request table those are many to many. user table have id,name,email and request have id,name, and pivot table have id, user_id and req_id